# What is a service?

Tags: language-agnostic

I keep hearing the term "service" a lot, but I have a vague understanding of it. Could someone explain what a service is citing some practical examples?

Comment: http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_a_service_in_computer_terminology

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the context. Very abstractly speaking, a service is some sort of program that offers some function, but the internals of which are completely opaque. I.e., a *web service* is something running somewhere on the web, having some sort of API which you can contact to get or submit some data. What exactly it does is none of your business, it just offers its *service* to you. On a system, for example a *Windows Service* may be a program running persistently in the background, doing *something*. Inside an application, you may have a *service layer*, which offers some functionality which you can use in the rest of the application through an API, but how exactly it works is irrelevant.

That's in contrast to, e.g., a function or library or class, which you usually import, manipulate, use more directly. A service is more self-contained, offering only its functionality with nothing much in the way of introspecting it.

Comment: That's very helpful. By the way, I recently read your article on encoding; good job with that!

Answer (score -1):

macdonald's is a service. you hand over some money, they give you a bigmac.

politicians are a service. you hand them your vote, they hand back lies and steal your lunch money, then charge you for doing so.

in computing terms, you hand over some data (a number, a string of text, etc..), the service takes that data, does something with it, and returns a result.

e.g. google translate is a service. google search is a service. godaddy's DNS registrar is a service. a computing service is no different than a real-world service.

Comment: What then, for example, is the difference between a "service" and a "subroutine"?

Comment: subroutine would be a sub-unit of a service, performing some function within the scope of that service. in macdonald's, that'd be "put_fries_in_fryer()" or "ring_up_incorrect_order()"